# I need to reference a fragment inside the same fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment that im trying to call a function from.

This code works when its in one of my activities, but i need it inside a fragment if possible.

This is the function im calling

```
new ActivityDumpUtil(AboutFragment.this, outfile, new ActivityDumpUtil.ActivityDumpCallback() {
```

I know the issue is AboutFragment.this

How do i call this inside my AboutFragment Fragment?
This is extending a Sherlock Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that if it works inside an `Activity`, then the first parameter should be an `Activity`, not a `Fragment`. You can get a reference to the hosting `Activity` inside a `Fragment` by calling `getActivity()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well that is passing the framgent AboutFragment into that method. and it worked when i have this in a activity by calling Settings.This (settings being the activity)

No in fragment i need to pass AboutFragment to the function. But AboutFragment.this doesnt work? I tried getActivity but its not an activity. what about getSherlockActivity?

Comment: @BigDX, What's the type of the argument?

Answer (score 0):

The `AboutFragment.this` is a reference the instance of AboutFragment that you're executing in.  Within the Activity you will need to give it the particular instance of AboutFreagment that you want to pass in the constructor for ActivityDumpUtil.  The FragmentManager is probably what you want.